# How to get horizontal alignment of headers

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have two headings, 'CompanyName' which appears top left, and 'Date' displays top middle.

I am having difficulty getting them horizontally aligned. I've tried putting them inside a div, but to no effect... How can I fix this problem?

```
<div>
    <h1>CompanyName</h1>
    <h1 style="text-align:center">Date @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TodaysDate)</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: You might want to provide more context, CSS etc, because text-align: center should work on h1 which is a block element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<div style="clear: both">
    <h2 style="float: left;width: 40%;">CompanyName</h2>
    <h2 style="/* float: right; *//* text-align: center; */">Date @Html.DisplayFor(model =&gt; model.TodaysDate)</h2>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
div {
    text-align:center;
    background:green;
}
div h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    background: red;
    margin: 0 auto
}
h1:first-child {
    display:inline-block;  float:left
}
```

**[DEMO UPDATED 2](http://jsfiddle.net/yTAjb/2/)**

Comment: yeah, thanks but thats not what I am looking. I want all the text on the same horizontal line...?

Comment: Add `display:inline-block` or `display:inline` to `h1 tag`. Check the updated demo

Comment: thanks nearly there. that produces the text all together. I want CompanyName at top left, and date at top centre.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<div style="display:table">
    <h2 style="display:table-cell">test1</h2>
    <h2 style="display:table-cell">test2</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation of how `display:table` and `display:table-cell` solves the OP's question. This will help the OP  understand your code better and also helps future searchers.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
div{
    text-align:center
}
```

Comment: yeah, thanks but thats not what I am looking. I want all the text on the same horizontal line...?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a lineheight to your div and a vertical align.

```
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 40px
```

Comment: What if you add? display: table-cell;